# Is there a way to check document.ready() if jQuery is not available?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [$(document).ready equivalent without jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/799981/document-ready-equivalent-without-jquery)

I know you can use the window.onload event to make functions run, but is there a way for a script to query if the document is ready or not?

Something like

```
function update()
{
    if( !document.ready() )  // don't do unless document loaded
        return ;
}
window.setInterval( 'update();', 100 ) ;
```

Cannot change the <body> element, and no jQuery/other libraries.

Comment: @justkt The OP is not searching for a ready equivalent, but for a method to query whether or not the document has become ready.

Comment: @Šime - ready does check whether the document has become ready, then fires events if any are bound to it.

Comment: @justkt Binding a handler to the "ready" event is one thing and querying if the document is ready is another thing. The OP is doing the latter, and that other question the former. Those are two different things.

Comment: DOMContentLoaded event?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Here you go:

```
var tid = setInterval( function () {
    if ( document.readyState !== 'complete' ) return;
    clearInterval( tid );       
    // do your work
}, 100 );
```

Read about the `document.readyState` property [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.readyState). I am not sure if all current browsers implement it.

Comment: __Grrrrreat answer!!__ Tested Chrome, IE6,7,and 9, Firefox 4, Opera 11 it works.

Comment: Yes great answer indeed. Works in all major browsers. Sorry, the post is late, but still want to ask, 
Why is it needed to do setInterval for 100ms? Won't it still check without setInterval object.

Comment: @Yegya `setInterval` ensures that we keep checking *repeatedly*, every 100ms, until the document becomes `'complete'`.

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, I misthought for a second for setInterval to setTimeout. My bad... Thanx for calrifying though.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout https://github.com/jakobmattsson/onDomReady

It's more complicated than a few lines! - If you want multiple browser compliance.

Answer (score -6):

This code will work in all browsers

```
if(window.attachEvent()){

    window.attachEvent("onload",load);

 }else{

    window.addEventListener("load",load,true);

 }

 function load(){
    //Code to execute when the document is loaded.
 }
```

Comment: That, again, is the load, not the ready event. These are different.