# select option on change

Tags: javascript, ajax

i have json data like this:

```
[{
        "user_id": "113",
        "employe_first_name": "Asaladauangkitamakan",
        "employe_last_name": "Nasibb"
    }, {
        "user_id": "105",
        "employe_first_name": "Ryan",
        "employe_last_name": "Friday"
    }, {
        "user_id": "87",
        "employe_first_name ":"hendi ",
        "employe_last_name ":"kenther"
    }
]
```

how to 'create' select option with javascript (option `value = user_id`, and `text = employe_first_name`) that load when document ready, and fill another field with selected value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = [ {"user_id":"113","employe_first_name":"Asaladauangkitamakan","employe_last_name":"Nasibb"}, {"user_id":"105","employe_first_name":"Ryan","employe_last_name":"Friday"},   {"user_id":"87","employe_first_name":"hendi","employe_last_name":"kenther"} ];
var select = document.createElement("select");
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.value = data[i].user_id;
    option.innerHTML = data[i].employe_first_name;
    select.appendChild(option);
}
select.addEventListenter("change", function(event) {
    var selected_value = event.target.value;
    document.getElementById("another_field").value = selected_value;
});
someDiv.appendChild(select); // Add the select menu to the DOM
```

Comment: +1 but `document.createTextNode` instead of `option.innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var data = [ {"user_id":"113","employe_first_name":"Asaladauangkitamakan","employe_last_name":"Nasibb"}, {"user_id":"105","employe_first_name":"Ryan","employe_last_name":"Friday"},   {"user_id":"87","employe_first_name":"hendi","employe_last_name":"kenther"} ];
var select = document.createElement("select");
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = data[i].user_id;
        option.innerHTML = data[i].employe_first_name;
        select.appendChild(option);
    }
```

Here is [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hicurin/rgaRL/)

Comment: Are you really allowed to give the HTML of an element to `document.createElement`?

Comment: Sorry! what do you mean?

Comment: I mean it should be `document.createElement("option")`, you can't put `"<option value=...>"` there.

Comment: i have select option, and i wanna fill with json data, when select option change, i wanna append the value to another field

Comment: Sorry! I have some confusion with jquery. So I have just updated my answer. Please try it with jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
    //doing on dom ready
    var tid = setInterval( function () {
        if ( document.readyState !== 'complete' ) return;
        clearInterval( tid );       
        var json_len = json.length;
        var select = document.getElementById('select_id');
        for(var i=0;i<json_len;i++){
            var option = document.createElement('option');
            option.innerHTML = json[i].employe_first_name;
            option.value = json[i].user_id;
            select.appendChild(option);
        }
    }, 100 );
```

REFERENCE

[Is there a way to check document.ready() if jQuery is not available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706757/is-there-a-way-to-check-document-ready-if-jquery-is-not-available)

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery for the purpose, in this way .

Replace selectId with the id of your dropdown.

```
 var jsonData = [{
        "user_id": "113",
        "employe_first_name": "Asaladauangkitamakan",
        "employe_last_name": "Nasibb"
    }, {
        "user_id": "105",
        "employe_first_name": "Ryan",
        "employe_last_name": "Friday"
    }, {
        "user_id": "87",
        "employe_first_name": "hendi ",
        "employe_last_name": "kenther"
    }
];
    var ctrlSelect = $("#selectId");
    $(jsonData).each(function() {
        $("<option value='" + this.user_id + "'>" + this.employe_first_name + "</option>").appendTo($(ctrlSelect));
    });
```

Comment: Isn't it obvious? Who said anything about jQuery?

Comment: @Shea JQuery is not a different language. It is a javascript library.So one can use JQuery for any javascript task.That is why the answer is relevant here.