# createElement: How to make this cross-browser - works in IE10

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, css, readystate

I have the following javascript which is a loader that is triggered and created when the page is idle. It basically shows whilst the next navigated page is loading. The script resides on the (ASP.NET) master page and an Ajaxified user control.

I need to make the code cross-browser but not sure what the offender is.

It only works happily in Trident (only tested IE9 & 10) - not in Webkit or Gecko.

I'm not sure if it's a notation issue or if the page life cycle for Chrome and Safari don't ever declare themselves as "!= complete" thus not triggering the condition.

I'd also prefer to keep this a pure Javscript solution - no jQuery.

Thanks

```js
loader = 0;
if (window.location.href.indexOf("Login.aspx") < 0) {
    setInterval(function () {
        if (document.readyState != 'complete') {
            document.documentElement.style.overflow = "hidden";
            var navLoader = document.createElement("div");
            var loaderText = document.createElement("div");
            var loaderImg = document.createElement("div");
            navLoader.id = "navLoaderDiv";
            navLoader.className = "navLoader";
            loaderImg.id = "loaderImg";
            loaderText.id = "loaderText";
            loaderImg.className = "loaderImg";
            loaderText.className = "loaderText";
            navLoader.appendChild(loaderImg);
            navLoader.appendChild(loaderText);
            loaderText.innerHTML = "Working on it";
            var zedDepth = 99999;
            navLoader.style.zIndex = zedDepth;
            navLoader.style.background.image = "url(~/Images/loaderHalo2.png) 0 0 / 100% 100% no-repeat";
            navLoader.style.position = "absolute";
            navLoader.style.right = "0px";
            navLoader.style.left = "0px";
            navLoader.style.top = "25px";
            navLoader.style.bottom = "0px";

            if (loader == 0) {
                document.documentElement.appendChild(navLoader);
                loader = 1;
            }
        } else if (document.getElementById('navLoaderDiv') != null) {
            document.getElementById('navLoaderDiv').style.display = "none";
            document.documentElement.style.overflow = "hidden";
        }

    }, 1000)
}
```

Comment: Your snippet does not work... According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706757/is-there-a-way-to-check-document-ready-if-jquery-is-not-available#5706881), `document.readyState !== 'complete'` works fine in all browsers.

Comment: How are you calling this function? You might want to change `.style.background.image` to `.style.backgroundImage` and maybe it would be a good idea to `clearInterval` if your elements are already in the document

Comment: @skobaljik - thanks for your reply. The snippet works as intended in IE9, 10, 11 just not webkit. However, I have added the extra =.

Comment: @Kaiido - yes backgroundImage is better syntax. If I clear the interval it ceases to continue polling the page status, so it won't fire on the next page navigation.

Comment: hum if you change your page location, document is reloaded and javascript is re-executed. (except for `hashchange` only)

Comment: Thanks @Kaiido - sorry I should have explained the setup as well - the script resides on the (ASP.NET) master page and an Ajaxified user control is changed on navigation therefore the JS doesn't get reloaded - hence why I'm using polling.

Comment: you should edit your question then. + I'm not too much into asp.net (you should also add this tag to your question), but can't you just use an `addEventListener('readystatechange')` instead of polling ?

Comment: I'll check out readystatechange as an alternative - Cheers